# How to check which query or user caused SQL Server 100% CPU Utilization

Tags: sql-server

My SQL server 2016 database had 100% CPU Utilization issue at 06:30. Now I want to check which query or user caused this issue. I searched some articles online. They are all showing how to check it when the query is running. But what I want is to check history at 06:30. The database is fine now. So if I check the performance now, I can't find any query/job are running now. How do I check the history to identify the cause?

Comment: It's probably too late.

Comment: Do you have query store enabled? This will help you with the "what" - though not the "who". Look at the "Top Resource Consuming Queries" report for metric "CPU Time (ms)" with "Total" aggregation type for the time period of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from ssms, run the activity monitor for the server and look at recent expensive queries.

Comment: Yes that can show the queries. But it doesn't show the time and users that ran the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to investigate the top expensive parallel execution queries from sys.dm_exec_query_stat dmv, where max_worker_time is maximum CPU time.

```
Select Top 100 O.type_desc, O.name, S.creation_time, S.last_execution_time, S.min_elapsed_time, S.max_elapsed_time,
       S.Last_elapsed_time, S.Min_worker_time, S.Max_worker_time, S.Last_worker_time, S.execution_count,
       SUBSTRING (T.text, (S.statement_start_offset/2)+1, ((CASE WHEN S.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN DATALENGTH(T.text) ELSE S.statement_end_offset END - S.statement_start_offset)/2)+1)
From sys.dm_exec_query_stats As S Cross Apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(S.sql_handle) as T
                                  Cross Apply (Select type_desc, name From sys.objects Where object_id=T.objectid) as O
WHERE T.dbid = DB_ID() And
      S.Max_worker_time > S.Max_elapsed_time
Order by S.Max_worker_time Desc
```